# How to view details of particular id in laravel 8

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-8

Hi I am new to laravel and trying to create a dashboard, I have my database and I am able to load all the records from database into a table.
Now I want to get more details of particular id in new view which I am unable to get
Here is my code

MemeberController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\members;

class MemberController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $members= new members;
        $members_list= $members::all();
        return view('admin.members.index',compact('members_list'));
      // $arr['members'] = members::all();
        //return view('admin.members.index')->with($arr);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(members $members)
    {
        return view('admin.members.Details',compact('members'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Details Blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section('content')
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <div class="card-tools">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse">
        <i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="remove" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove">
        <i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body p-0">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="example2">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 10%">
                    Employee ID
                </th>
                <th style="width: 10%">
                    Role
                </th>
                <th style="width: 10%">
                    Region
                </th>
                <th style="width: 10%">
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            <tr>
            <td>
                {{ $members->Orglevel1 }}
            </td>
            <td>
               {{ $members->Role }}
            </td>
            <td>
               {{ $members->Region }}
            </td>
            <td>
    <a href="#modal-lg5" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-lg5" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">
            Feedback
        </a>
       </td>
   </tr>
  </table>   
 </div>

</div>
@endsection
```

and this is how I have give link in index blade

```
<td>
                <a href="/members/{{ $m->membersid }}">{{ $m->membersid }}</a>
            </td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Two steps you missed out above,

**1) web.php entry**

```
Route::get(/members/{memberID},"demoController@index")->name('member.show');
```

**2) Show function**

```
 public function show($memberID)
    {
       $member= Member::findOrFail($memberID); //This will fetch the respective record from the table. 
        return view('admin.members.Details',compact('member'));
    }
```

And you could call the route in index as,

```
<td>
<a href="{{route('member.show',$m->membersid)}}">{{ $m->membersid }}</a>
</td>
```

Hope this would have answered your answer. Let me know if you any queries further.

Comment: @migtyteja I am using resource controller will this work with resource controller as well?

Comment: Could you please elborate your query